# Classes of inserted DOM node not being passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, comparison

I have the following code that listens for an inserted DOM node

```
$('#box').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var news = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if (news[news.length-1].indexOf("today")){ 
        //do something                     
    }
});
```

When a node is inserted, the code above is supposed to check the class to see if it has the string "today". The structure of the inserted html is like this...

```
<div class="posts news today">
```

If it has "today", it's supposed to "do something"

The issue is that for some reason, the function above is showing that inserted nodes have a class of

```
""
```

Even though the element that was inserted is

```
<div class="posts news today">
```

However, elements that already exist show the correct class of

```
posts news today
```

The issue lies in this code somewhere, but I'm not sure why inserted nodes would be interpreted to not have a class while existing nodes do.

For clarification, this code

```
$('#box').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var news = e.target.className;
    console.log(news);
});
```

outputs the correct class name for elements that already exist on page load, but shows "" for inserted elements. As stated above, the inserted elements contain the correct class information, it just isn't being interpreted by the code above.

Comment: Can you show us where you're inserting?

Comment: -1 == true, you need to test if indexOf equals -1 rather than just equating it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Just use `if ($(e.target).hasClass("today")) {`

Comment: The issue isn't that the class isn't being compared correctly, it's that no class info is being detected with inserted nodes, only existing ones. The classes definitely exist though.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you insert the new DIV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using jQuery anyway -- why not use it everywhere?

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('today')) {
   // ...
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass

Comment: The issue isn't that the class isn't being compared correctly, it's that no class info is being detected with inserted nodes, only existing ones. `e.target.className` is equal to "" on inserted nodes.

Comment: Can you show us a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that does this? This one works fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zuWKk/

Comment: I wonder if it matters that `<div class="posts news today">` isn't a complete node without a closing tag. You should add your DOM-insertion code to your question.